# Cocos2d touch dispatcher causing object retain

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, touch, dealloc

I have a problem with cocos2d. I made a class which receives touches. Class is a subclass of `CCLayer` and `init` looks like so:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frameSize
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        frame = frameSize;
        size = frame.size;
        origin = frame.origin;
        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] touchDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
    }
    return self;
}
```

So everything is kept simple. `frame`, `size` and `origin` are class variables but this does not matter right now. So I register my class witch `touchDispatcher` which allows me to handle touches. The touch handling is done like so:

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //Some touch logic which i need.
}
```

And in `dealloc` I release all the retained information and unregister from `touchDispatcher`. But the `dealloc` is never called. If I dont register with `touchDispatcher` the `dealloc` is called properly. If important, this class is added as a child in another CCLayer subclass and in that class's `dealloc` I release this one.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

to clarify giorashc's answer, do this. :

```
- (void)onEnter {
    [super onEnter];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector].touchDispatcher addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
}

- (void)onExit {
    // called before the object is removed from its parent
    // force the director to 'flush' its hard reference to self
    // therefore self's retain count will be 0 and dealloc will
    // be called.
    [super onExit];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector].touchDispatcher removeDelegate:self];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You said it yourself : the touch dispatcher is retaining your layer object as you used it as a delegate in `addTargetedDelegate`. So you must un-register your layer from the dispatcher from **somewhere else** or else the final release will never get called (so `dealloc` will not be called).

In short : Do not un-register touch dispatcher from the dealloc method if the delegate is the same object